# vscode open golang project,Could not import local package

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

1. project can be built successfully,it's work.
2. `vscode(or gopls)` show errors `'could not import **** package'`
3. Goland will not have this problem, But I want to use vscode remote

The project structure is as follows:

Assume modName is MyProject

```
- GoPath
     * MyProject   -----  open project
         * cmd
             * main
         * internal
             * package1
                 * goFiles   ---- import "MyProject/internal/package2"    //show errors
             * package2
                 * goFiles
```

What should I change to let the error go away?

Answer (score 0):

Packages in Go should b structured as go modules. Read from the documentation or refer here - https://golangbot.com/go-packages/

It is a practise to import packages in go as

> github.com/prateekgupta3991/refresher/entities

even though its in the same project, instead of absolute path in your local.

Try to align the package structure in go mod format. Might solve your problem.

Comment: My project mod name is MyProject,import local package "modName/internal/package2".Project can be built successfully. Some local packages will report errors in vscode.The same problem does not appear in goland.i want to use vscode remote.

Comment: Few pointers - are you using vsc remote with WSL in windows? Can you check your vsc settings for go. Even i had vsc settngs issue with go in linux initially.